# I need to add a perspective grid in orthographic view for grease pencil layer

Tags: 3d-view, grease-pencil

I need to add a grid mesh on top of my grease pencil layer so it would be easier for me to draw things into perspective. What is a good way of doing this? Right now I am going to download a grid image so I can import into Blender as a background. Any other quicker way?

Comment: I think this is probably your best bet right now. With [Background Images](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/background_images.html), you can put the image in front of or behind your drawings. Blender 2.8 will include more Grease Pencil features, so that might be an option next year.

Comment: Press Shift+A to get the add menu and select "Grid". Set the number of subdivisions you need. Then enter edit mode, select all the faces and press delete. On the delete menu select "delete only faces"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

**Steps to make a dynamic non-destructive 2d grid in blender:-**

> 1. Add a **Plane**
> 2. Add a **SubSurf** modifier
> 3. Change the subdivision algorithm to simple
> 4. Add a **Wireframe** modifier
> 5. Tweak the subdivision levels and the wireframe thickness to adjust grid size and density

Here's the blend file:-
[image]

> I have added a Shadeless material to the grid for easier viewing which may suit your purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the effort! I actually found using an image as bg is easier!